# Reverse Yoneda: Nat(F, Hom(c, -)) in bijection with F(c)?

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

The Yoneda lemma states that for a locally small category $C$ and a functor $F: C \rightarrow Set$, for each object $c \in C$, there is a bijection between the set of natural transformations $[C, Set](Hom(c, -), F)$ and the set $F(c)$.

In particular, this talks about natural transformations *from* $Hom(c, -)$ *to* $F$. Can we talk about the reverse? I am looking for a theorem of the form:

> For a locally small category $C$ and a functor $F: C \rightarrow Set$, for each object $c \in C$ such that `???`,  there is a bijection between the set of natural transformations $[C, Set](F, Hom(c, -))$ and the set $F(c)$.

If such a result is not possible, I'd like to understand what the obstacle to having such a result is.

Comment: You might be interested in reaing the nLab page about "Isbell duality".

Comment: One obstacle is that $[C,Set](F,Hom(c,-))$ is contravariant in $F$ and $c$ while $F(c)$ is covariant in both.

Comment: If you assume $F$ is representable by an object $d$, then you're asking for a nice bijection between $\mathrm{Hom}_C(c,d)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_C(d, c)$ for all $c \in C$, but when $c \neq d$ in general you probably don't expect such a thing. I can't think of any naturally occurring categories where this would happen.

Comment: General advice for beginners in category theory: consider the edge cases first, so for example categories with just one object (=monoids), or discrete categories (=sets), or thin categories (=posets). This way you will quickly see that there is no such result here.